# how to give color in the select field and option field?

Tags: html, forms, css

I made contact form in my website and I want to add color in my select field like other fields. Right now when I choose one of any option in Select field, no option is showing in that field. What mistake I am doing here? Please check issue on the following link.

http://shahfahad.com/demo/contact.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Comment: You might want to post the code handling this particular element (css & html)

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing the color of each `option` tag inside your `select` tag via CSS.

For example:

```css
select option {
    background-color: green;  
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Please choose</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Note that you don't have to target all `select` tags in your CSS, you can also use its id

This should answer your question if I understood correctly.

Comment: but why my select is not showing my option ? when I choose one of any option , there will be no display in select field

Comment: After reviewing your code a little bit via chrome dev tools I have discovered that the problem lies in your `form-control` class. Perhaps the `background:none;` is what causes the problem of your option not showing in the select field. Try deleting or changing that code and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to view the code with Mozilla's inspector and successfully test the problem. 
The problem was that you have your `color` property was set to be `inherit` so  it'll be the same color of your background. That just makes it invisible. Instead set the property to a visible color other than the same one. Try this snippet.

```css
.form-control {
    background: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    height: 44px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 26px 10px 26px 15px;
    color: black !important; /* Set the text color to be black, not inherited to the background */
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: black;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
button, select {
    text-transform: none;
}
option {
    margin: 0;
    font: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-color: black; /* Set the text color to be black, not inherited to the background */
 }
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #414141;
}
html {
    font-size: 10px;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
 ;
}
/* Change the background of all choices */
option {
background-color: blue;
color: gray; /* This is the color of text */
}
#Responsive {
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
 <h2> You could change the background/color of all options. </h2>
<select id="form_service" name="service" class="form-control" title="Please Select Your Service" required="" data-error="Select Your Service.">
 <option disabled="">Choose Your Require Service</option>
  <option value="Responsive Website Desin">Responsive Website Design</option>                                        
 <option value="Wordpress Website Design">Wordpress Website Design</option>
  <option value="Only Template/PSD Design">Only Template/PSD Design</option>
 <option value="PSD to HTML">PSD to HTML</option>
  <option value="PSD to Wordpress">PSD to Wordpress</option>
 <option>Banner Design</option>                                        
</select>
 <h2> You could change the background/color of a specific option. </h2>
<select id="form_service" name="service" class="form-control" title="Please Select Your Service" required="" data-error="Select Your Service.">
 <option disabled="">Choose Your Require Service</option>
  <option id="Responsive">Responsive Website Design</option>                                        
 <option>Wordpress Website Design</option>
  <option>Only Template/PSD Design</option>
 <option>PSD to HTML</option>
  <option>PSD to Wordpress</option>
 <option>Banner Design</option>                                        
</select>
```